# how to get todays time using mktime

Tags: php, mktime

I tried to get todays time at 00:01:00 (h:i:s)

my code:

```
<?php 
$delay_hour=10;
$delay_minute=11;

echo $t2=mktime($delay_hour, $delay_minute, 00, date('n',time()), date('j',time()), date('Y',time()));
echo '<br/>';
echo date("d-m-Y h:i:s",$t2);
echo '<br/>';
$delay_hour=0;
$delay_minute=1;

echo $t2=mktime($delay_hour, $delay_minute, 00, date('n',time()), date('j',time()), date('Y',time()));
echo '<br/>';
echo date("d-m-Y h:i:s",$t2);
echo '<br/>';
?>
```

so how to get todays time at 00:01:00?

Comment: MKTime returns a GMT timestamp. You will probably find that you have an offset/timezeone set in your php.ini file.

Comment: You don't need to pass date part into `mktime()` since by default it's today

Comment: @AlmaDo want to find today 00:01:00 so that will not comes in time()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to just:

```
$result = mktime(0,1,0);//hour, minute, second
```

Because [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime) without date part passed to it will set date to today's date.

Note also, that `mktime()` results in *timestamp* - i.e. it's not formatted date, it's integer value (equal to number of seconds passed since Unix Epoch beginning)

Comment: still it shows 1396985400,//Tue, 08 Apr 2014 19:30:00 GMT

Comment: It __can not__ show `"Tue ..."`. It will show _timestamp_ - so please, post the code for formatting your output

Comment: Something is wrong. `mktime()` [works fine](http://3v4l.org/jP0WS) - see fiddle. Note that `h` and `H` are different

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump(strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 00:01:00'));
```

or

```
$date = new DateTime('today 00:01:00');
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // formatted
var_dump($date->format('U')); // timestamp
```

or

```
var_dump(mktime(0, 1));
```

If you need formatted representation, it is prefered to use second approach, with `DateTime`. If you need timestamp, use third, with `mktime`

Comment: your code is working for me,its giving 2014-04-09 00:01:00
1396981860, but now here how to pass my date $t2, because it may be diffrent date